# How to read the first line from a file as key and the next 3 lines as a list of values to a dictionary, python

Tags: python, file, dictionary, file-read

I'm trying to read a `txt` that look like:

```
Animals
Dog
Cat
Bird
Cities
Paris
London
Chicago
```

into a dictionary. (The first line into a key followed by three lines of values, and so on) It should be looking something like this:

```
{"Animals":["Dog","Cat","Bird"],"Cities":["Paris","London","Chicago"]
```

Please help me!

Comment: What have you tried? And what's puzzling you in your attempts?

Comment: Do you have some code already? We do not mind helping out when you get stuck, but we generally do not like writing your whole program!

Comment: Is your data always ordered in pairs of a specific type with three corresponding values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import itertools

d = {}

with open("C:\path\to\text.txt", "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

    # Separate keys from values
    keys = itertools.islice(lines, 0, None, 4)
    first_values = itertools.islice(lines, 1, None, 4)
    second_values = itertools.islice(lines, 2, None, 4)
    third_values = itertools.islice(lines, 3, None, 4)

    # Set keys and values
    for key in keys:
        key = key.rstrip()
        value1 = first_values.next().rstrip()
        value2 = second_values.next().rstrip()
        value3 = third_values.next().rstrip()

        # Create dict
        l = [value1, value2, value3]
        d[key] = l
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using `islice`, that helps you select the next n lines to read from a file.

```
from itertools import islice

dic = {}

with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    while True:
        lines = list(islice(f, 4))
        lines = map(str.rstrip, lines)
        if not lines:
            break
        dic[lines[0]] = lines[1:]

print dic
```

That gives the result you need:

`{'Cities': ['Paris', 'London', 'Chicago'], 'Animals': ['Dog', 'Cat', 'Bird']}`

More on [islice](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice)

Comment: Why wouldn't you just `{line.strip(): [s.strip() for s in islice(f, 3)] for line in f}`?

Comment: Didn't think of that! Thank you for the tip!

Comment: You could also `stripped = map(str.strip, f);d = {line: list(islice(stripped, 3)) for line in stripped}` which would remove the strip calls, presuming python3 and it  may be a bit faster.You can also remove the ugly lambda with `map(str.rstrip, lines)` in your own code ;)

Comment: Little bit better now! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
ind = 0
my_dict = {}
my_list = []
for line in myfile:
    val = line.rstrip().split()[0]
    ind += 1
    if ind % 5 == 0:
        my_list = []
    if ind % 4 == 1:
        x = val
    else:
        my_list.append(val)

    if ind % 4 == 0:
            my_dict[x] = my_list

print(my_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
f = open('first.txt').readlines()
f = [i.strip('\n') for i in f]
datafile = [i.split() for i in f]


dct = {}


for i in range(len(datafile)):

    if i%4 == 0:

        new_lst = datafile[i+1:i+4]

        final_list = [b[0] for b in new_lst]

        print datafile[i][0]
        dct[datafile[i][0]] = final_list




print dct
```

Comment: This is a perfectly reasonable solution, along with the others below. Could the downvoter explain his motive?

Comment: Same here! At least they should point out the problem with yours and my solutions. I am up-voting yours.

Comment: Same. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another possible solution:

```
fin = open(f, 'rb')

lines = [word.strip('\n') for word in fin.readlines()]

keys = [word.strip('\n') for idx, word in enumerate(fin.readlines()) if idx%4 == 0]

values = [lines[idx+1:idx+4] for idx, _ in enumerate(lines) if idx%4 == 0]

d = dict(zip(keys, values))

{'Animals': ['Dog', 'Cat', 'Bird'], 'Cities': ['Paris', 'London', 'Chicago']}
```